# Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' using DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I writing phone verification functional via Twilio and using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`

I inject it in AppService like this

```
 public class TwilioVerifyClientAppService: IVerifyPhone
    {
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public TwilioVerifyClientAppService(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<TwilioSendVerificationCodeResponse> StartVerification(int countryCode, string phoneNumber)
    {
        var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("via", "sms"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("country_code", countryCode.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("phone_number", phoneNumber),
        });

        var response = await _client.PostAsync("protected/json/phones/verification/start", requestContent);

        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // this will throw if the response is not valid
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwilioSendVerificationCodeResponse>(content);
    }


    public async Task<TwilioCheckCodeResponse> CheckVerificationCode(int countryCode, string phoneNumber,
        string verificationCode)
    {
        var queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"country_code", countryCode.ToString()},
            {"phone_number", phoneNumber},
            {"verification_code", verificationCode},
        };

        var url = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("protected/json/phones/verification/check", queryParams);

        var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);

        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // this will throw if the response is not valid
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwilioCheckCodeResponse>(content);
    }
}
```

}

When I try to run method, I get this error

Here is how I call this method in controller

```
     [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class ProfileController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUserProfile _profileAppService;
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IFileUpload _fileUpload;
        private readonly IVerifyPhone _verifyPhone;

        public ProfileController(IUserProfile profileAppService,
            UserManager<AppUser> userManager, IFileUpload fileUpload, IVerifyPhone verifyPhone)
        {
            _profileAppService = profileAppService;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _fileUpload = fileUpload;
            _verifyPhone = verifyPhone;
        }
[Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmCodeSend([FromForm] PhoneInputDto input)
        {
            var result = await _verifyPhone.StartVerification(input.DialingCode, input.PhoneNumber);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                return Ok("Code sent");
            }

            return BadRequest();
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmCodeCheck([FromForm] PhoneInputDto input)
        {
            var result =
                await _verifyPhone.CheckVerificationCode(input.DialingCode, input.PhoneNumber, input.VerificationCode);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                return Ok("Phone verified");
            }

            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate
>   'TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure.AppServices.UserProfile.TwilioVerifyClientAppService'.

In `Startup.cs`
I register my interface like this

```
services.AddScoped<IVerifyPhone, TwilioVerifyClientAppService>();
```

I tried to write this in Startup.cs

```
services.AddHttpClient<TwilioVerifyClientAppService>();
```

But I still see this error.

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You registered the class as a typed client but not the interface, yet try to inject the interface as a dependency into the controller.

Update the typed client registration to include the interface

```
services.AddHttpClient<IVerifyPhone, TwilioVerifyClientAppService>();
```

provided `TwilioVerifyClientAppService` is derived from `IVerifyPhone`

```
public class TwilioVerifyClientAppService: IVerifyPhone {
    //...
}
```

and remove the scoped registration

```
services.AddScoped<IVerifyPhone, TwilioVerifyClientAppService>();
```